# Access denied issue in IE ajax call in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am using ajax calls to post data on a server and it is seems to be working in a Mozilla and Chrome however it is not working in IE. I am using below code

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://xxxxxx',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: success,
            error:error
        });
```

Every time I am getting below error on IE console
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

Please help!!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903550/how-to-solve-the-error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x80070005-ac

Comment: What version of IE? Are you running off the file protocol or via http (not with the s)? Is it a cross domain call?

Comment: I am testing it in IE 11. I am using HTTPS and hitting server is also https. Yes it is a cross domain call. I am testing through my localhost/It is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla. Only issue with IE